# Vector of object from a custom class

Tags: c++, class, vector

In C++, I declare a custom class to store some values for an object. Then, I declare a vector of said object. Finally, I iterate through the vector to assign values to the fields.

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Custom
{ 
    public:
        int metric,nX,nY;
    private:

};

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

vector<Custom> MyWonderfulVector;

// Some code//

for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++){

MyWonderfulVector[i].metric = computation1();
MyWonderfulVector[i].nX= computation2();
MyWonderfulVector[i].nY= computation3();
}

return 0;

}
```

It throws a `vector subscript out of range` when it tries to evaluate `MyWonderfulVector[i].metric = computation1();`. `metric` is an int and `computation1()` too. at the first iteration, i=0 so it should be ok. Curiously, somewhere else in the code, I have a vector of another class (included in a library) and this syntax works for it, so I don't understand why it doesn't work here.

**EDIT :**

Ok with the comments I changed to following line:     vector MyWonderfulVector(10);

So my problem is that I did not initialize the size of the vector (bad habit from Matlab ;) ) From what I understand, if I don't initialize the vector's to a fixed size, I must push_back the objects to "increase" the size of the vector. So, I should create a temporary Custom Object to assign the fields, then push_back this temp object into the vector. If one of the commenter wants to put this into an answer...

Comment: Does your `MyWonderfulVector` has objects ? You need to allocate objects to the vector by a `push_back` operation. Did you do that in the code you didn't show ?

Comment: I suspect `some_variable > MyWonderfulVector.size()`. Your problem is likely somewhere in `// Some code//`.

Comment: No, it is empty. What I want to do is like: "vector<int> MyIntVector"

Comment: Then give it a size, like `vector<Custom> MyWonderfulVector(some_variable);`. Even with the `int` case, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: I changed the loop to limit the iter to 10

Comment: When you execute your for loop, what do you expect to be in the vector?

Comment: Ok Fred Larson is right, I gave the vector a size on initialization. Ways to do it dynamically without using push_back?

Comment: @Doombot You can use `resize` to set the size of the `vector`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You defined a vector with no elements

```
vector<Custom> MyWonderfulVector;
```

If you call its member function `empty` like

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << MyWonderfulVector.empty() << std::endl;
```

then you will get `true`

So you may not use the subscript operator applied to an ampty vector except with index 0 but in any case you may not assign a value.

You could either define the vector initially with `some_variable`  elements like

```
vector<Custom> MyWonderfulVector( some_variable );
```

and then you could use your loop. Or you could reserve space for `some_variable`  elements in the vector and in this case use member function `push_back` instead of the subscript operator. For example

```
vector<Custom> MyWonderfulVector;
MyWonderfulVector.reserve( some_variable );


for ( int i=0 ; i<some_variable ; i++ )
{
    Custom obj;
    obj.metric = computation1();
    obj.nX= computation2();
    obj.nY= computation3();

    MyWonderfulVector.push_back( obj );
}
```

Comment: Hahaha this exactly what I was about to do. Thanks!

Comment: So the reserve is preallocating memory. Ok I'll add that!

Comment: @Doombot You are right. reserve preallocates memory for future elements that can be added by means of push_back

Comment: @@Doombot  Take into account that you may use push_back without reserving memory. But in this case the memory will be reallocated each time when a new element is addeed. So it is more efficient to reserve memory that there will not be a reallocation.

Comment: _"But in this case the memory will be reallocated each time when a new element is addeed"_ Huh? Since when?

Answer (score 9):

You declare a `vector` of `Custom`s in the line

```
   vector<Custom> MyWonderfulVector;
```

but it is an empty `vector`. There are no items in it. When you try to access the elements of the `vector` in the `for` loop, you are accessing the `vector` using out of bounds indices.

I can think of the following options for fixing that problem.

1. Create the `vector` with an initial size.

   ```
    vector<Custom> MyWonderfulVector(10);
   ```
2. Add to the `vector` in the `for` loop.

   ```
   for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++){
     Custom c;
     c.metric = computation1();
     c.nX= computation2();
     c.nY= computation3();
     MyWonderfulVector.push_back(c);
   ```

   }

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem before. I tried using the push_back function from vector class and it worked. Maybe it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Vectors are not like arrays. You need to use [push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/)

Comment: He's not adding items to the vector, he's getting a reference to the object at `i` and assigning a value to one of it's members.

Comment: @Stormenet Except what if there isn't an object at `i`? Then you get a `vector subscript out of range` exception.

Comment: @sjdowling You won't get any such exception unless you use `.at(i)` instead of `[i]`.  If you use the `operator[]` method to get or set elements out of range, it's simply undefined behavior.

Comment: @cdhowie According to the standard and in release mode. However most implementations do bounds checking on `operator []` in Debug which is what Doombot is seeing.

Comment: True, I am in debug mode of MSVS C++.

Answer (score 0):

Try using resize() before accesing an element.
So your code will become:

```
for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++){

MyWonderfulVector.resize(i);

MyWonderfulVector[i].metric = computation1();
MyWonderfulVector[i].nX= computation2();
MyWonderfulVector[i].nY= computation3();
}
```

If you further want to add some other elements, you can store the size of the vector in size_t variable, and increment it every time you want to add other element.

```
size_t my_vector_size = MyWonderfulVector.size();
for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
{
    my_vector_size++;
    MyWonderfulVector.resize(my_vector_size);
}
```

This is a way to do it.